# Refactor my code, how can i write these line in one block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>  </li> 
    <li><%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %> </li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Add Post', :controller=>'/posts', :action=>'new' %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %></li>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to write these line of code inside one block ?
Can anyone post a shortcut way? Too much <% %> , <% end %>

Comment: iam confused why have you added two if statements?

Comment: Edited, now make it shorter, less <% .. %>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's wrong with doing it like this?

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>  </li> 
    <li><%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %> </li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Add Post', :controller=>'/posts', :action=>'new' %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok, but is there any way to reduce <% %> , <% end %> ?

Comment: Ruby is not my thing, but if this templating works the same way as pretty much every other system out there I can't see any way to simplify this further.

Comment: If you wanted to get rid of the `end` line and make your templates a little less verbose, try using HAML.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is pretty normal for ERB. If you would like to reduce some extra formating you can use [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/):

```
- if user_signed_in?
  %li= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)
  %li= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path)
  %li= link_to 'Add Post', :controller=>'/posts', :action=>'new' 
- else 
  %li= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)
```

To use or not HAML imho is a matter of taste.